# Starting conda pompt from cmd

Tags: python, windows, cmd, anaconda

I want to start the conda Prompt from cmd, because I want to use the promt as a terminal in Atom.io.

There is no Conda.exe and the path to conda uses cmd to jump into the prompt. But how do I start it inside of cmd?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is to change to Anaconda shell using cmd, you can find the address for your Anaconda and run the following in your cmd:
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" "Address"\anaconda3

Or, you can find your Anaconda prompt shortcut, right click on that, and open its properties window. In the properties window, find Target. Then, copy the whole thing in Target and paste it into your cmd.

Comment: sadly not, it just gives me some commands but non of them starts a prompt I think

Comment: I guess what you want is Anaconda shell, not conda. So you can find the address for your Anaconda and run the following in your cmd: %windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" "Address"\anaconda3

Comment: Or, you can find your Anaconda prompt shortcut, right click on that, and open its properties window. In the properties window, find target. Then, copy the whole thing in Target and paste it into your cmd.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#starting-conda. Also check this guide https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/.